# Weird behavior of LSTM predictions (Keras, TF) on self-generated time series

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm

I have designed Python code using Keras + TF ) that predicts a self-generated time series (a sinusoid + a linear trend) using a simple LSTM model.
When predicting the sinusoid alone, it works OK.
However, when I add the linear trend line, it gets out of whack and I can't bring it to fit it 'good enough'. The last predicted time steps are always off.
Why is it behaving this way?

```
# LSTM for international airline passengers problem with memory
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import read_csv
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix

def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

# fix random seed for reproducibility
tf.random.set_seed(7)

# load the dataset
dataframe = read_csv(r'C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Python Scripts\airline-passengers.txt', usecols=[1], engine='python')
dataset = dataframe.values
dataset = dataset.astype('float32')

dataset = (np.sin(np.arange(0,500))*10 + np.arange(0,500)).reshape(-1,1)

# normalize the dataset
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset)*0.5)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]

# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 5
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], trainX.shape[1], 1))
testX = np.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], testX.shape[1], 1))

# create and fit the LSTM network
batch_size = 1
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 1), stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
for i in range(100):
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()

# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX, batch_size=batch_size)
model.reset_states()
testPredict = model.predict(testX, batch_size=batch_size)

# invert predictions
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
trainY = scaler.inverse_transform([trainY])
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
testY = scaler.inverse_transform([testY])

# calculate root mean squared error
trainScore = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY[0], trainPredict[:,0]))
print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
testScore = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY[0], testPredict[:,0]))
print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))

# shift train predictions for plotting
trainPredictPlot = np.empty_like(dataset)
trainPredictPlot[:, :] = np.nan
trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back, :] = trainPredict

# shift test predictions for plotting
testPredictPlot = np.empty_like(dataset)
testPredictPlot[:, :] = np.nan
testPredictPlot[len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:len(dataset)-1, :] = testPredict

# plot baseline and predictions
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(15, 5))
plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(dataset))
plt.plot(trainPredictPlot, label='train prediction')
plt.plot(testPredictPlot, label='test prediction')
ax.legend(loc="lower left")
plt.show()
```

[image: Model results]